# How to create a new raw type for Parcelable

Tags: kotlin, parcelable

I have two classes.

One is the `Message` class, and it contains a `Reaction`
Reaction can be decoded from a single string. 
I decode from an object that looks like this:

```
{
[ ... message fields ... ],
"reaction" : "reactionCryingWithLaugh"

}
```

The code looks like this:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
@Parcelize
data class Message(
    @get:Exclude override val id: String? = null,
    val creationDate: Timestamp? = null,
    val mime: String? = null,
    val senderId: String? = null,
    val text: String? = null,
    val emoji: Reaction? = null
) : Parcelable

data class Reaction(val name: String, val id: Int): Parcelable {
    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel?, flags: Int) {
        dest?.writeString(name)
    }

    override fun describeContents (): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Reaction> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Reaction {
            val name = parcel.readString()
            require(name != null)
            val reaction = reactionList.find { it.name == name }
            require(reaction != null)
            return reaction
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Reaction?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}

 val reactionList = arrayOf(
     Reaction("reactionCryingWithLaugh", R.drawable.ic_reaction_crying_with_laugh)
     [...]
     )
```

When I try to deserializes it fails without even stepping into `createFromParcel`

How to implement this properly ?

> I get the error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize
>   object. Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type
>   net.sevendays.alpaca.ui.chat.Reaction (found in field
>   'lastMessage.emoji')

Comment: Why `Reaction` does not have `@Parcelize` annotation?

Comment: @BartekLipinski because it's implemented by hand, not autogenerated by the annotation

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to deserializes it fails without even stepping into createFromParcel

This is because you are deserializing JSON, `Parcelable` is only used to read/write [`Parcel`s (an Android-specific binary format)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel).

There are very many Java libraries for serializing to JSON, but `@JsonClass` annotation comes from Moshi (most likely; maybe it's a different library which happened to use the same name), so you'll need to write a [custom type adapter](https://github.com/square/moshi#custom-type-adapters) for `Reaction`. It should be as simple as

```
class ReactionAdapter {
  @ToJson 
  fun toJson(reaction: Reaction): String = reaction.name

  @FromJson 
  fun fromJson(text: String): Reaction {
    val reaction = reactionList.find { it.name == name }
    require(reaction != null)
    return reaction
  }
}
```

and then registering it wherever the `Moshi.Builder` is created.